# Trying to click labels inside input

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**html code:**

```
<input id="19eb0353-6208-4baa-8f89-f7af0a6edb91" type="date" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" name="dateOfBirth" data-componentname="dateOfBirth" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" data-ddlabel="dd" data-mmlabel="mm" data-yyyylabel="yyyy">
```

ID is dynamic

Trying to enter the day month and year but not sure how to write it

I know this is the data but cant find anything on selecting these specific labels inside the input

data-ddlabel="dd" data-mmlabel="mm" data-yyyylabel="yyyy"

Tried Xpath, css selector but the ID is dynamic

Comment: Hi @n00be, Welcome to StackOverflow. There are ways to operate on elements with dynamic attributes, based on pattern of dynamic values or sometimes using the sibling/parent elements with fixed attributes, etc. Please check other similar questions. If you cannot solve the issue, then you need to provide more details with HTML data of the page(sharing the link would be best if possible) and also the code which you have tried.

Comment: @Kamal The URL is https://www.nike.com/us/en_us/s/register, Click join at the bottom and then the registration form will come up. I cannot enter in a day, month and year at all.

Comment: @n00be Please try the code in my answer below. Let me know if it does not work, accept the answer if it works :D

Comment: What xpath expressions have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below css.

```
input[type='date']
```

or the below xpath

```
//input[@type='date']
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: The URL is nike.com/us/en_us/s/register, Click join at the bottom and then the registration form will come up. Tried to run your code and didn't see any change.

Answer (score 0):

when registration page opens (after clicking join now), you can use xpath like "**//select[@id='nike-unite-date-id-mm']**" to select date, month and year separately (like dropdown).

OR

you can directly point to specific date using xpath 
"**//select[@id='nike-unite-date-id-mm']//option[contains(text(),'10')].click()**" 
this will directly select the date, similarly can be done for months and year by changing  **@id**

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

I have tested, it worked for me.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='date']")).sendKeys("04/04/1989");
```

Please let me know if you face any error.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can try this (example using python):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

month = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('nike-unite-date-id-mm'))
month.select_by_visible_text("08")

day = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('nike-unite-date-id-dd'))
month.select_by_visible_text("21")

year = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('nike-unite-date-id-yyyy'))
month.select_by_visible_text("2019")
```

And use Select Method like this:

```
<option value="01"> 01 </option>
                    ^^
select_by_visible_text("01")

<option value="01"> 01 </option>
        ^^^^^^^^^^
select_by_value("01")
```